# Is the series $\sum_{n=1}^\infty\ln(1 + a_n)$ convergent or divergent?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, derivatives

We are given that $\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n$ is convergent, and we want to know if $\sum_{n=1}^\infty\ln(1 + a_n)$ is convergent or not.

I used the limit comparison test.

We get$$ \lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\frac{\ln(1+a_n)}{a_n}.$$

And using L'Hospital's rule, I get
$$\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\frac{\ln(1+a_n)}{a_n} = \lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\frac{\ln(1+a_n)'}{{a_n}'} = \lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\frac{\frac{1}{1+a_n}(a_n)'}{{a_n}'} = \lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\frac{1}{1+a_n}=1.$$

However, we must know that $a_n$ can be convert to a differentiable function then we can use L'Hospital's rule, so I am just confused, is there any way to prove this, or can we prove that $a_n $ can be converted to a differentiable function?

I also took a look at the same questions/answers, but none of these answered my question.

Comment: We know only that $a_n$ converges or also that $\sum a_n$ converges? If the latter then we must have $a_n \to 0$ and you can use the known limit $\log(1+x)/x \to 1$ as $x\to 0$.

Comment: Presumably $a_n>0$?

Comment: @Gary but you use L'Hospital's rule, right? How do you know that you can use this rule?

Comment: We know nothing about the range of  $a_n$

Comment: For $\log(1+x)/x\to 1$ you can use L'Hospital or there are other proofs of this limit. Then you can just use the fact that if $\log(1+x)/x\to 1$ when $x\to 0$, then for *any* sequence $a_n$ that converges to $0$ we also have $\log(1+a_n)/a_n\to 1$. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Limit_of_a_function#In_terms_of_sequences in general.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Infinite_product#Convergence_criteria

Comment: @Gary I kind of understand your meaning, so let $g(x) = \ln(1+x)/x$ , and we can get $\lim_{x\rightarrow0}g(x) = 1$, and since $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}a_n = 0$(means $a_n$ converges to $0$), we can get $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}g(a_n) = 1$, so $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\ln(1+a_n)/a_n = 1$. But if so it seems that it works all the time, how about the answers posted by other people, the discussion they posted below seems also plausible.

Comment: @Stanley The problem is that in order to apply the [limit comparison test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Limit_comparison_test), you need $a_n>0$. My comment was on how to apply the test provided the conditions are met.

Comment: @Gary I see, thanks a lot

Answer (score 2):

This is **not true** in general, let $a_n = \frac{(-1)^n}{n^{\frac5{12}}}$,

$$\ln \left(1 + \frac{(-1)^n}{n^{\frac5{12}}}\right) = \frac{(-1)^n}{n^{\frac{5}{12}}} -\frac12 \times \frac1{n^{\frac{10}{12}}} + \mathcal O\left(\frac1{n^{\frac{15}{12}}}\right)$$

which is not convegent since $\frac{10}{12} < 1$

However if $a_n$ is positive the proof is easy since $$0 \le \ln \left(1 +  a_n\right) \le a_n$$

Comment: Indeed, Wikipedia uses the example $a_n=\frac{(-1)^n}{\sqrt{n}}$, where $\sum a_n$ converges but $\prod(1+a_n)$ diverges to $0$.

Comment: Yes! $a_n = (-1)^n / n^a$ with $\alpha < 1$ should work.

Comment: what methods do you apply in this, I am just kind of confused from the first equation.

Answer (score 1):

We are given $\sum a_n$ converges.

(1). If $a_n>0, $ series $\sum \ln(1+a_n)$ converges. (since $0\le \ln(1+a_n)\le a_n$)

If the sequence $a_n$ is alternating, at least we can say following:

(2). Suppose $\sum a_n$ converges and $\sum a_n^2$ diverges, then $\sum\ln(1+a_n)$ diverges.

**Proof:** Since series $\sum a_n$ converges, it means $a_n\to 0$, there exsits a number $N$, such that $|a_n|<\frac{1}2, \forall n\ge N$

$\forall x\in\left[-\frac{1}2, \frac{1}2\right]$, we can show for a constant $C$, where $0<C<\frac{2}9$, we have:

$$x-\ln(1+x)\ge C x^2$$
Let $x=a_n$, and we require $\sum a^2_n$ diverge, for example, $a_n=\frac{(-1)^n}{\sqrt n}$
$$\sum_{n=N}^ma_n-\sum_{n=N}^m\ln(1+a_n)\ge C\sum_{n=N}^ma_n^2$$

Let $m\to \infty$, since the RHS diverges, it means the LHS must diverge, but since $\sum a_n$ converges, it means $\sum\ln(1+a_n)$ diverges.

Comment: And why you are doing all this?

Comment: This shows under the conditions that $\sum a_n$ converges and $\sum a_n^2$ diverges, then $\sum\ln(1+a_n)$ diverges.

Comment: I think that this is an overcomplicated method for a simple task.

Answer (score 0):

Since $\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n$ is convergent, we can come to the conclusion that

$\lim_{x \to \infty} a_n=0$

Otherwise, $\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n$ won't be convergent

Now, the main problem is the sign of $a_n$, $\ln(1+a_n)$, and $\frac{\ln(1+a_n)}{a_n}$ is not clear.

We can ***Only*** use comparison test when both are **absolutely convergent**.

However, in this case, we do not have enough proof to say $a_n$ is absolutely convergent.

Thus, the comparison test is meaningless.

Also, I cannot think of any way of applying Dirichlet's Rule or Abel's Rule on this problem.

Further Discussions are welcomed